# Replace jaxb XmlJavaTypeAdapter in POJO in third party library

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using third party library to convert XML messages to POJO.
That library uses jaxb annotations.
Example of one of classes.

```
        package com.xxx.convert;

        import java.util.Date;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
        import com.xxx.convert.jaxb.extensions.DateTimeAdapter;
        ......................

        @XmlRootElement(
            namespace = "http://xsd.com/xxx/convertor",
            name = "NonTradingOrder"
        )
        @XmlType(
            name = "NonTradingOrder",
            propOrder = {"requestor", "valueDate", 
"raised", "state", "description", "rawOrder"}
        )
    @XmlSeeAlso({CashInOrder.class, 
CashInterAccountTransferOrder.class, 
CashOutOrder.class})
        public abstract class NonTradingOrder extends Order {
            private UserRef requestor;
            private LocalDate valueDate;
            private Date raised;
            private OrderState state;
            private String description;
            private String rawOrder;
        ..........
            @XmlAttribute(
                name = "Raised",
                required = true
            )
            @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
            public Date getRaised() {
                return this.raised;
            }
        .......
        }
```

I run into a problem in class com.xxx.convert.jaxb.extensions.DateTimeAdapter. 
Currently, I need to process messages from new source that I have not previously processed. And I found that this library does not understand date time format from new source.

I could not change format of Date Time in source messages.

I could ask to fix problem in library, but it takes about two month and I do not have that time.

The library contains about 100 classes for different types of messages and I do not want to rewrite it. And currently I have a lot of code that use this library.

**Does anyone have ideas for HOT FIX of that problem ?**

*Some additional information:*

class com.xxx.convert.jaxb.extensions.DateTimeAdapter

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = 
           new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");
.......
    public Date unmarshal(String value) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat var2 = this.dateTimeFormat;
        synchronized(this.dateTimeFormat) {
            this.dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            return this.dateTimeFormat.parse(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Message example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<proto:Message xmlns:tr=............>
    <proto:MainObject>
        <tr:NonTradingOrderNew EventTime="2017-06-26T12:21:38.6397505+03:00">
            <tr:Order xsi:type="tr:CashInterAccountTransferOrder" 
            ID="...." 
            CreationTime="2017-06-26T12:21:38.6397505+03:00" 
            ValueDate="2017-06-26" 
            Raised="2017-06-26T12:21:38.6397505+03:00">
                <tr:Requestor ID="6019" Name="......." />
                <tr:State Status="Executing" StatusDate="2017-06-26" />
                <tr:Source ..... />
                <tr:Target ..... />
                <c:Amount Value="300000.00" Currency="EUR" />
            </tr:Order>
        </tr:NonTradingOrderNew>
    </proto:MainObject>
</proto:Message>
```

Main code to process messages:

```
import com.xxx.convert.Message;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class SerializerEx {

    private static JAXBContext context;

    private static void initIfNeed() throws JAXBException {
        if (null == context) {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(
                    Message.class
            );
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String xmlText) {
        try {
            initIfNeed();
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlText);
            Object ddmObject = unmarshaller.unmarshal(stringReader);
            return ddmObject;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Cannot read xml message for " + xmlText, ex);
            context = null;
            return null;
        }
    }

    .........................
}
```

I had one attempt to solve the problem, but I failed.

I created new data time processor (I use java 8)

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateTimeAdapterNew extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

........

    public Date unmarshal(String value) throws Exception {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(value);
        java.util.Date date = Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
        return date;
    }
}
```

And create file package-info.java in package com.xxx.convert

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=Date.class,
                value=DateTimeAdapterNew.class),
})
package com.xxx.convert;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;

import java.util.Date;
import com............DateTimeAdapterNew;
```

But exception was raised in test:

```
 Cannot read xml message for <?xml version="1.0"?>
<proto:Message .........>
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of ........NonTradingOrder
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:690) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.XsiTypeLoader.startElement(XsiTypeLoader.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:559) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at ...........SerializerEx.deserialize(SerializerEx.java:51) [classes/:?]
```